# How to set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS environment variables on Linux on a Windows Machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

Currently using Python = 3.5 and Spark = 2.4 versions.

I am trying to run `PySpark` in a Linux context (git bash) on a `Windows` machine and I get the following:

```
set PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--name" "PySparkShell" "pyspark-shell" && python3
```

Does anyone know where I should set these variables? I couldnt't find anything that works for me on google.

`spark-shell` with `Scala` works, so I am guessing is something related to the `Python` config.

Comment: You need add them in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Follow here: https://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? I am facing the similar issue, Please guide me with the steps